# How to deploy MSI which has no silence install switch?

Tags: windows-installer, google-workspace

How can I deploy a MSI package that does not support "silence" install switch?

The one I am trying to deploy is [GSSMO](https://support.google.com/a/answer/148484#install) "google suite sync for MS outlook". it is a MSI package and it is only supported to be published by gpo, users have to install it themselves from "add/remove programs" on user level

I want to deploy this one on computer level and there is no switches supported by this MSI.

Is there any better way to deal with it without repack it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Silent installation is a built-in feature of Windows Installer and should work for all MSI files** (unless actively blocked by modifications in the MSI file in question).

Here is a sample `msiexec.exe` command line to install the MSI file silently:

```
msiexec.exe /I "enterprise_gsync.msi" /QN /L*V "msilog.log"
```

**Quick parameter explanation:**

```
- /I - run installation sequence.
- /QN - run completely silently.
- /L*V "msilog.log" - create verbose log file.

All paths have been removed from the command line above. Please add as appropriate.
```

In a few cases badly designed MSI files can cause installation to be incomplete when run silently, but in most cases you should be OK.

Please leave a comment and let us know how deployment works out for you, particularly if you see any problems.

Comment: This is the way I use to run silent install all the time. but this msi created by Google is not working at all for some reason. it does not support any switch at all. even `xxxx.msi /?`  go ahead for a test

Comment: Did you try making a verbose log and have a look what it says? Try searching for "value 3" to find any errors in there. Use the command line above to try.

Comment: `MSI (s) (3C:78) [13:05:22:439]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: G Suite Sync™ for Microsoft Outlook® 4.0.7.0. Product Version: 4.0.7.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Google, Inc.. Installation success or error status: 0.`   It did work this time if I run it on local machine directly. I guess my issue must be related to `psexec` for remote installation. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it. I am not too familiar with psexec - perhaps just add another question for details? Maybe you would have more luck with these types of questions on http://www.serverfault.com? (system administrator site).